# sortBy of p:dataTable inside a ui:repeat does not work

Tags: sorting, jsf, primefaces, uirepeat

I have a problem here.

I'm using a `<ui:repeat>` to create datatables, because the user can select from a other datatable multiple rows that create these multiple datatables.

It's all working fine, but the `sortBy` does not.

How can I use the `sortBy` here?

```
<ui:repeat var="something" value="#{SomeClassManagedBean.somethingHere}">
  <p:dataTable value="#{something.rows}" var="row" sortBy="#{row.value2}">
    <p:column headerText="Value 1" sortBy="#{row.value1}">
       <h:outputLabel value="#{row.value1}" />
    </p:column>
    <p:column headerText="Value 2" sortBy="#{row.value2}">
       <h:outputLabel value="#{row.value2}" />
    </p:column>
    <p:column headerText="Value 3" sortBy="#{row.value3}">
       <h:outputLabel value="#{row.value3}" />
    </p:column>
  </p:dataTable>
</ui:repeat>
```

Comment: try to add a rowkey in your datatable and delete the `sortBy="#{row.value2}"` from the datatable

Comment: which PF version are you using?

Comment: @yagami_light: I have tryed that, but doesn't work too :(

Comment: @kukeltje: PF 6.0

Comment: Try a p:repeat then. See if it makes a difference

Comment: `p:repeat` don't make difference

Yesterday I have used `p:subDataTable` to create this multiple tables, but the problem is the same: `sortBy` don't work.

Answer (score 0):

I have fixed the problem.
Hope this can help other developers with the same issue.

I just used `p:tabView` and `p:tab` instead `ui:repeat`.

The tables are more organized now and everything is working fine.